# How to query DTED offline using ArcGIS .Net SDK?

Tags: .net, gis, arcgis, esri, arcgis-runtime

Our application needs to do some elevation calculations (and is not connected to the internet), as a result we need to determine the highest elevation for a given polygon. How can we query DTED offline using ArcGIS .Net SDK?

Here is the little progress I have made...

**Option 1 - Use Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Controls.FileElevationSource**

So in order to use FileElevationSource it turns out it must be associated with a SceneView. We were only using a MapView so I added in a SceneVeiw and associated the FileElevationSource

```
sceneView.Scene.Surface.Add(elevationSource);
```

When I tired to access the elevation source I get an AccessViolation

```
elevationSource.GetElevationAsync(location as MapPoint).Result
```

**Option 2 - Some how use LocalServer**

The doco states that ArcGIS Runtime LocalServer support a number of Raster formats including DTED.
[Local Server raster support—ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .NET](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/10-2/desktop/guide/local-server-raster-support.htm)
So I used ArcMap to create a map package file with the DTED files within but have no idea how to use Local Sever to query the package file

Ultimately we want to:

1. Load a number of DTED files
2. Query for a given lat/lon what the elevation is at that point

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

*Note we are using ArcGIS .Net SDK v10.2.7*

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the result of an async operation until it completed.
Instead try this:

var result = await elevationSource.GetElevationAsync(location as MapPoint);

We'll have better support for getting elevation directly from any raster soon, (hopefully Update 1, but might be U2).